# Retrofit - JsonSyntaxException when trying to get response.body

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit, retrofit2

So I am trying to get response.body from my server, which is list of type GpsCordinates.

From server I get response like this:

```
[
{
"x": 33333,
"y": 333,
"date": 1516532556000
},
{
"x": 3,
"y": 4,
"date": 1516542914000
}
]
```

Request:

```
@GET("....")
    Call<List<GpsCordinates>> getGPSCordinatesForDay();
```

how I get the response:

```
Api api = Api.RetrofitInstance.create();
    api.getGPSCordinatesForDay().enqueue(new Callback<List<GpsCordinates>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<GpsCordinates>> call, Response<List<GpsCordinates>> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                List<GpsCordinates> gpsCordinates = response.body();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<GpsCordinates>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("ERROR", t.toString());
        }
    });
```

GpsCordinates model:

```
 @SerializedName("x")
@Expose
private double x;
@SerializedName("y")
@Expose
private double y;
@SerializedName("date")
@Expose
private Date date;

public double getX() {
    return x;
}

public void setX(double x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public double getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setY(double y) {
    this.y = y;
}

public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

And when I try it I get:
**D/ERROR: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 1516532556000**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **long** instead of `Date`. Your server sends timestamp (millis).

Comment: In my server date is also of type java.util.Date